# Add values to array cookie

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, cookies

I need to add new variables to an array, that is stored in a cookie. How could i do this ?

```
var arr = $.cookie("arr",[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]);
// this is an array of diferent numbers

function pri() { // this function create a number that is not in the array
var n = Math.floor((Math.random() * 15));
var tex;
while ((tex = $.inArray(n, arr)) != -1) {
    n = Math.floor((Math.random() * 15));
}
return n;} //i need for whatever "n" is to be added to my array cookie
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $.cookie plugin will save the array as an string, and this :

```
var arr = $.cookie("arr",[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]);
```

returns the request, something like :

```
arr=1%2C2%2C3%2C4%2C5%2C6%2C7%2C8%2C9
```

you have to first save the array, then get the string back and split it again, then you can push to it :

```
$.cookie("arr",[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]); // set the cookie

var arr = $.cookie("arr").split(',');        // get the string and split it

arr.push(pri()); // then add whatever the function returns
```

now you can save the modified array back in the cookie

```
$.cookie("arr", arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Values in cookies can only be strings so use a (un)serializer.

JSON works fine in JavaScript:

```
$.cookie("key", JSON.stringify([ 1, 2, 3]);
```

Usage:

```
function add_value(new_value) {
    var value = JSON.parse($.cookie("key")); // unserialize
    value.push(new_value);                   // modify
    $.cookie("key", JSON.stringify(value));  // serialize
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be $.cookie("key", JSON.stringify(value); instead of $.cookie("key", JSON.stringify([ 1, 2, 3]); ?